# ThermodynamicData finding enthalpy for saturation liquid/vapor

Tags: physics, curated-data

In my course literature these variables are called hf/hg where they also are listed in a table. Now to my question, how do i find this data with the help of Mathematica?

My assignment is to find the thermal efficiency of a rankine cyckle with the given data.

```
> Data


    T3 = 480 + 273.15;
    P3 = 15 10^6;
    substance = "Water";
    P4 = 7.5 10^3;
```

So let's start with State 4

```
> Units



    Pa = Quantity[1, "Pascals"];

    [ScriptCapitalK] = Quantity[1, "Kelvins"];



> Tables

    h[p_, T_] = 
      ThermodynamicData[substance, 
         "Enthalpy", {"Pressure" -> p Pa, "Temperature" -> T \[ScriptCapitalK]}] //
         QuantityMagnitude // Quiet;
    s[p_, T_] = 
      ThermodynamicData[substance, 
         "Entropy", {"Pressure" -> p Pa, "Temperature" -> T \[ScriptCapitalK]}] //
         QuantityMagnitude // Quiet;
```

Now by knowing the pressure in state 4, 7.5 kPa i can find hf/hg from the table in the literature which is 168.75/2574 kJ/kg. Is there any way to find this data in Mathematica aswell?

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this:

```
p = Quantity[7.5, "Kilopascals"];

t = ThermodynamicData["Water","LiquidVaporPhaseBoundary", 
    {"Pressure" -> p}]

ThermodynamicData["Water", "Enthalpy", 
    {"Temperature" -> t}]

ThermodynamicData["Water", "Enthalpy",
    {"Temperature" -> t, "Pressure" -> p}]



(*   313.44 K           *)
(*   168830. J/kg       *)
(*   2.57403 10^6 J/kg  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

"Quality" determines the state of the fluid at saturation, with 0 being liquid and 1 being vapor.

```
p = Quantity[7.5, "Kilopascals"];
ThermodynamicData["Water", "Enthalpy", {"Pressure" -> p, "Quality" -> 0}]
ThermodynamicData["Water", "Enthalpy", {"Pressure" -> p, "Quality" -> 1}]

(*   168746. J/kg       *)
(*   2.57403 10^6 J/kg  *)
```